# References when loading XAML Workflows

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

I'm learning about Windows Workflow Foundation 4, and tried to create the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Activities.XamlIntegration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xaml;

namespace BranchedActivities
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity wf = ActivityXamlServices.Load(@"C:\...\Workflow1.xaml");
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Workflow1 comprises of a single action, calling Activity1. Activity1.xaml comprises of a single Writeline.

When I load the workflow as a compiled Activity  (by using "Activity wf = new Workflow1()"), the program loads perfectly.
When I try to load the XAML for the activity (like the code above), the get the exception: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:}Activity1'.

I guess I have to somehow load the other xaml file as well, though I'm pretty stumped on how.

For your reference.... Workflow1.xaml:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Workflow1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="262,240" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:">
  <Sequence sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="C:\...\Workflow1.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="222,200">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <local:Activity1 sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Activity1.xaml

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Activity1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="273,240" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Sequence sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="C:\...\Activity1.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="233,200">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="211,61" Text="Hello World" />
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I need to manually reference the dll's that were generated. The working code I used was:

```
XamlReader xamlReader;
//Assembly wfAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Assembly wfAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"Workflows.dll");
XamlXmlReaderSettings settings = new XamlXmlReaderSettings();
settings.LocalAssembly = wfAssembly;
xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(@"Workflow.xaml", settings);
Activity wf = ActivityXamlServices.Load(xamlReader);
```

I have to compile the Workflows in visual studio itself. Once they're in a library, I reference them as above.

Comment: [Alternative for this is to load all compiled activities from the dll](https://gist.github.com/nickdevereaux/592ddffb38c5697b0c21). In my example I've got a directory that only has compiled workflow activities but you could do this to any directory, will take a lot longer of course

Answer (score 0):

Since your xaml is not a loose xaml, but rather a xaml with code behind (a class), you can not load the xaml by itself.

Try removing the attribute `x:Class="Activity1"` from the `Activity` element.
- If your activity has no members (methods, fields, properties) in the code behind, then you don't really need the code behind.

(Same regarding the attribute `x:Class="Workflow1"`.)

Edit:

The `xmlns:local=` (or any other namespace e.g. `xmlns:src=`, `xmlns:x=`, `xmlns:srd=`) attribute is only to be use to reference types within a custom or system namesspace other that the default (`xmlns=`).

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"` is not a valid namespace mapping, since it isn't mapped to anywhere!

You are using the local namespace in one place: `<local:Activity1 sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />`, so you do need the mapping, however, you'll have too correct it. (E.g. `xmlns:local=MyCompany.MyProject.SubNameSpace`, assuming you are referencing the same DLL as the xaml is in.)

*If you want the xaml to load as loose xaml, you will need to added the assembly name to the definition too.* E.g. `xmlns:mms=MyCompany.MyProject.SubNameSpace;AssemblyName` - not `local`, since loose xamls don't have a local ns.)

Comment: I removed the x:Class= attribute from both the xaml documents. But I still get the exception: "Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:}Activity1'."

Answer (score 0):

Refer all the dependent dll (those are used to develop activities and workflow) in the project where you are using main function.

Comment: I tried that. But it didn't seem to take those references into account